# Is it possible to loop through all downloaded emails in native iPhone mail app?

Tags: ios, swift

I've found a few articles on core Mail 2 but what I didn't find is how I can loop through all emails within the native iPhone mail client. So basically I want to read all emails into an object or dictionary. Then loop through all those and extract subject and body into a local database. Finally I want to run through all records and add a classification based on subject and body text. So basically I want to label the emails. As this should work offline I thought there must be a way to do that.
Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your app is sandboxed. It cannot look into the iPhone's Mail app's storage.

Comment: Thank you, Matt.